# Chief Sensory Cells

Tags: terminology, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy

What makes the second order neurons of posterior grey horn of spinal cord to be called as "chief" sensory cells?

Why don't we call 1st order, or third order neurons or other second order neurones in different part of spinal grey part as "chief" ?

Comment: Eh, searching on Google a bit, this terminology seems limited to two Indian sources: one textbook and one study guide, and isn't used anywhere else. There is a different area called the "chief sensory nucleus" which is separate. It just seems to be an attempt by those couple sources to refer to the cells which aren't one of those other categories. It isn't meant to indicate some special significance for those cells versus cells at other hierarchical levels, rather simply trying to classify different cell types within the spinal cord.